# Bluebird complete async loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I want to iterate over a large array such that it won't hang the browser, so I want each iteration to be async.

Both `BlueBird.mapSeries(arr, (e) => console.log(e));` and `BlueBird.each(arr, (e) => console.log(e));` are blocking so nothing happens until they finish.

Is BlueBird even the right framework for this? Is there another framework for this?

Comment: first, what is a "large" array to you? About how many items are we talking here? and second, what operation do you want to perform on them? And `item => console.log(item)` is not really representative for the speed of your final code. The console is not meant to log *(and show)* hundreds or thousands of items at once. IMO the bottleneck here is most likely the logging not BlueBird.

Comment: 500,000 and each iteration isn't trivial. @Thomas, I'll check without the logging. Edit: it hangs the browser...

Comment: Doing 500k non-trivial iterations in the browser seems to be the wrong approach. What are you trying to do?